# How to get the names of images with regular expression, sed and grep from an HTML file

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed, grep

I would like to write out the names of the images in a html file using regex, grep and sed.

This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple title</h1>
    <img src="cat.png" alt="nice cat"></img>
    <img src="carrot.jpg" alt="yumm"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following regex:

```
/.*<img src="(.*?)" .*>.*/g
```

With it, I got this on regexr.com with the replace function on the first group:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple title</h1>
cat.png
carrot.jpg
</body>
</html>
```

But how can i get only the two names of the file?
I tried using sed and grep/egrep, but with no luck.

With sed, i tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/.*<img .*src="(.*?)" .*>/\1/g' index.html  > pc_temp.txt
```

But this give me an error:

```
sed: -e term # 1, character 31: invalid reference (\ 1) to the "s" command for RHS
```

So i am lost now.

Any idea, how to modify my command or my regex, to get the names of the files?

Comment: That's the problem with using an online tool to create or validate a regexp for a command-line tool - every command-line tool supports a specific variant of regexp (BRE, ERE, or PCRE) and has various options, delimiters, and caveats to consider so any regexp you create/validate with an online tool will have very limited applicability when trying to include it in a command-line tool. In this case there are no standard UNIX tools that would understand the regexp you came up with on that web site (there are non-standard tools that might, but no version of sed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egrep -o '<img src="[^"]+"' index.html | cut -d\" -f2 > pc_temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You're really making this hard on yourself by trying to use a complicated regexp and multiple tools. Any time you find yourself considering using sed+grep, just use awk instead:

```
$ awk -F\" '/<img/{print $2}' file
cat.png
carrot.jpg
```